# Can I make a bevel curve transition to another one during the same bevel process?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

My situation is as follows:
I want to create a curved plane that has a crease or ditch at one end and is flat at the other.
To achieve this, I created a curve (curve 0) that defines my plane, then used another U-shaped curve (curve 1) to bevel the first one, creating the actual plane with the ditch or crease (the U shape of the crease or ditch being defined by curve 1).

Now my question is: can I create a third curve (curve 2) that is just a straight line and have the bevel transition from curve 1 to curve 2 over the distance of curve 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to to morph a bevel from one curve to another.  If you want a blend a curved plane from one profile to another you need a NURBS surface.

[image]

1. Add (<kbd>Shift + A</kbd>) a Surface, NURBS Curve.
2. Edit the curve to the profile you want for one end of the surface.
3. Duplicate (<kbd>Shift + D</kbd>) the curve and move it along the Y-axis.
4. Flatten out the curve control point by scaling them in the Z-axis.
5. Select both curves and press <kbd>F</kbd> to loft them into a surface.

Comment: Thanks! This looks exactly like what I want. How did you do this?

Comment: Added some instructions for you.